# Unable to come out of the powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have below code written in powershell where i am calling a vbs script and trying to install a service which is working fine but post that the script never closes automatically

```
CScript.exe "C:\Program Files\AppDynamics\machineagent-bundle-64bit-windows-21.12.0.3201\UninstallService.vbs"
```

Below is the output

```
Attempting to Stop Machine Agent Service
Stopping service 'Appdynamics Machine Agent'.
Service stopped

Uninstalling AppDynamics Machine AgentService from the Service Manager
Service is already stopped.
Uninstalled service 'Appdynamics Machine Agent'.

Done.
Removing Machine Agent VM options

Done.
```

After tgis the screen remains here and it never exits until i dont mention exit. So i want to integrate this step in pipeline which is working but the pipleine keeps on running as it never comes out of this.

Comment: is it CScript.exe that is never closing or is it the window that is calling CScript.exe that is never closing?

Comment: @Otter It is the window that is calling Cscript.exe which is never closing. So i am calling this from powershell and after execution it doesnt close by itself

Comment: I would then take a look at how the pipeline is executing the command as in theory this would be a problem for calling any script/file, not only CScript. What are you using to execute this?

Comment: @Otter I am trying to uninstall a appdynamics machine agent service. So if do this from powershell ISE also i face this issue it never stops its execution

Comment: @Otter is there a way to execute this script within 10 sec and then exit from here

Comment: Try appending `; exit` to your command, this will just call exit after the script is done executing! `CScript.exe "C:\Program Files\AppDynamics\machineagent-bundle-64bit-windows-21.12.0.3201\UninstallService.vbs"; exit`

Comment: @Otter i tried this but no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240339/discussion-between-otter-and-ashish).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It creates a background job that it monitors. Once it detects `Removing Machine Agent VM options`, it flips a boolean that makes the next instance of `Done.` terminate the background job, which terminates the process right along with it.

```
function Watch-UninstallMA {
  param([Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)][Management.Automation.Job]$vbs)
  :monitor do {
  foreach ($line in ((Receive-Job $vbs) -split "`n")) {
    Write-Output $line
    if ($line.Trim() -eq 'Removing Machine Agent VM options') { $removedvmo = $true }
    if ($line.Trim() -eq 'Done.' -and $removedvmo) { break monitor }
  }}
  while ($vbs.HasMoreData -and $vbs.State -eq 'Running')
  Remove-Job $vbs -Force
}

Start-Job { cscript.exe ($env:PROGRAMFILES +
"\AppDynamics\machineagent-bundle-64bit-windows-21.12.0.3201\UninstallService.vbs")
} | Watch-UninstallMA
```